# Public methods in ASPX page getting used in other scripts

Tags: c#, accessor

We had a very strange issue on our servers this week, where a method in an aspx script (with no code-behind file) was somehow getting called from completely unrelated pages elsewhere on our site. Basically, the script said this:

```
   <script language="c#" runat="server">
   public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        // some initializer logic
        PageMethod("data");
   }
   public string PageMethod (string strInput) 
   { 
        // More logic
   }
   </script>
```

We operate a farm of four servers, and we were seeing the `PageMethod` getting called by scripts in several places on all servers, so while my first instinct was that this was a corrupted cache on the server (and I still suspect it might be), my gut tells me that we were allowing this to happen with our code. We've been using this code style for yonks, but recently upgraded our servers to .NET    2.0.

My first question is, should a `public` method in an aspx every be accessible to a script elsewhere on a website? And my second question is, should we be using `private` or `protected` methods on aspx pages (I always figured the code in a stand-alone page was self contained, so sloppy access modifiers shouldn't make a difference).

(Note: I don't write much c#, so my grasp of the language is pretty much just theoretical. I'm just trying to troubleshoot this issue before it becomes a real issue.)

Comment: Can you provide more info on what you see/saw and therefore what drove you into thinking that these methods are being call from unrelated pages? Where are you "seeing" PageMethod being called? In your logs? What is the complete url in such cases?

Comment: Is it possible that there are other pages that have a method called "Page_Method"? Without knowing how you've determined (or think) that other requests are calling into this specific page's methods its hard to say.

Comment: @Shiv Kumar, our server captures the stack trace of all unhandled exceptions, so I can see the `Page_Load` of the script that crashes, and immediately after the `Page_Load` I see the call to `PageMethod`. But there is absolutely no linkage between the two pages. It almost looks like a buffer overflow problem.

Comment: can you show us the stack trace? The stack trace is in reverse order. In that the first method you see is the last method and the method before it is the method that called it. And why is the Page_load crashing? That is the error exactly and does that error make sense (is it expected)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My first question is, should a public method in an aspx every be accessible to a script elsewhere on a website?

In order to invoke a public instance method, an instance of this class is required. I suspect that your issue is not related to other scripts calling this method directly. It's more probable that there is an HTTP request being sent to the corresponding ASPX page which in turns invokes the method. This request could be done by the client (some link on a page, ...) or directly by the server (using HttpWebRequest). To further debug the problem try looking at the web server log files to see all the requests being made to this page.

> And my second question is, should we be using private or protected methods on aspx pages (I always figured the code in a stand-alone page was self contained, so sloppy access modifiers shouldn't make a difference).

If those method are not intended to be used by other parts of the code it is a good practice to make them private or protected and that's not only related to ASP.NET.

Comment: Thanks Darin. I commented to @Shiv this as well, but what I'm seeing in the stack trace is the `Page_Load` being invoked on the other, unrelated script, immediately followed by the public method call of this script. I'm not getting line numbers returned in the stack trace, so I can't be 100% sure that the `Page_Load` I'm seeing actually belongs to the script the user is calling, but I can't see any reason for it to get misdirected. There is absolutely no linkages between the two scripts.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably best to make methods like PageMethod private or protected. The Page_Load and other page lifecycle methods have to be public I believe, but the rest do not. The classes that asp.net generates *can* be accessed like any other class, though sometimes they're tricky to find. Where I usually see weirdness like that is when someone has copied an aspx page but neglected to change the page directive, so that you have multiple code in fronts pointing at a single code-behind.